# I'm trying to send a password reset link to my email through phpmailer this is the error its showing

Tags: xampp, phpmailer, forgot-password

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php:2212
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(2019): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1678): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Mon, 22 M...', '\r\n <h2>Hello...')
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1516): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend()
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dreams_figma/login/password_reset_code.php(42): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dreams_figma/login/password_reset_code.php(59): send_password_reset('name_hidden', 'tyaginiharika11...', 'ccdb0363f917aa2...')
#5 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 2212
```

idk what to do help...

Comment: The first place you should look for problems with any package is its own documentation, and the docs on this specific issue can be found [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#authentication-failures). You might like to think about using some error checking too, so that your code fails cleanly instead of allowing an uncaught exception.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If you need help, please share the code involved